# torch.Tensor() new() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (list, dtype=torch.dtype)

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am facing a very weird error when I am trying to run the following simple line :

```
a = torch.Tensor([0,0,0],dtype = torch.int64)

TypeError: new() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (list, dtype=torch.dtype), but expected one of:
 * (*, torch.device device)
      didn't match because some of the keywords were incorrect: dtype
 * (torch.Storage storage)
 * (Tensor other)
 * (tuple of ints size, *, torch.device device)
 * (object data, *, torch.device device)
```

whereas if we look at official documentation

```
torch.tensor(data, dtype=None, device=None, requires_grad=False, pin_memory=False) → Tensor
```

> Parameters
>
> data (array_like) – Initial data for the tensor. Can be a
> list, tuple, NumPy ndarray, scalar, and other types.
>
> dtype (torch.dtype, optional) – the desired data type of returned
> tensor. Default: if None, infers data type from data.

Why is the code snippet not working even though the official documentation supports it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Capitalization matters -- in your top example, you have `Tensor` with uppercase T, but the documentation excerpt is talking about `tensor` with lowercase t.

Comment: Do you have link where "Tensor()" function is defined? As I couldn't find the capital t, I had initially assumed the small t and capital t were the same (maybe capital T was an alias of the small t)

Comment: @infiNity9819 Majority of modern programming languages are case-sensitive. Here, `torch.Tensor` is a class, `torch.Tensor(...)` is its constructor, and `torch.tensor(...)` is a function that creates an instance (probably calls the constructor alongside some other magic). It seems that constructing `Tensor` instances directly using the constructor is not supported. (In other languages, the constructor would be set to private, but Python does not support this.) The [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor) lists supported ways of constructing a tensor.

Answer (score 2):

As Jan's answer said  but here I will explain why
**Tensor** different from **tensor**

**torch.Tensor** is an alias for the default tensor type (torch.FloatTensor).
**which is a CPU tensor**, **32-bit floating-point** so the type and device are predetermined.

> #This will cause an Error, because  Tensor has no dtype and device properties on it's constructor
>
> ```
> example_tensor = torch.Tensor(
>     [
>      [[1, 2], [3, 4]], 
>      [[5, 6], [7, 8]], 
>      [[9, 0], [1, 2]]
>     ]
> , dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
> ```

To move a tensor to a new device, you can write **new_tensor = example_tensor.to(device)** where the device will be either CPU or Cuda.
and to set new type you can use **new_tensor.dtype=torch.float64** for example

```
     example_tensor = torch.Tensor(
    [
     [[1, 2], [3, 4]], 
     [[5, 6], [7, 8]], 
     [[9, 0], [1, 2]]
    ]
)
    new_tensor = example_tensor.to(device)
    new_tensor.dtype  #set or get dtype
```

1. 

### this is from the documentation

A tensor **(case senstive tensor not Tensor)** of specific data type can be constructed by passing a torch.dtype and/or a torch.device to a constructor or tensor creation op:

```
cuda0 = torch.device('cuda:0')
torch.ones([2, 4], dtype=torch.float64, device=cuda0)
```

.